# Importing node with multiple values with node export and feature

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, migration

I have a custom content type in Drupal 7. The scenario is, I have a content type **album** which have a image field with multiple values option enabled.
When I import the feature in another drupal 7 setup, the import fails.
Please help.

Comment: Can you write down the steps which you are taking ?

Comment: After enabling features modules, I create a feature (Admin->structure->feature). In that dialogue box, I tick the Album from content type, and from node Export I tick the required nodes. But when I enable the feature in another drupal 7 setup, the content type is created but I get an error on importing nodes of the same content type.(Dependencies, if any, are taken care of.)

Comment: How are you importing nodes ?

Comment: Nodes are imported automatically when the profile is installed. I am able to import node with single fields but not this album content type.